# Re: jQuery Multiple Checkbox Page Filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox, filter

This question is an extension of [jQuery Multiple Checkbox Page Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526029/jquery-multiple-checkbox-page-filter) .  It's my question exactly.

I have three goals:

- I want to have a list of check boxes to filter Page Content.
- I want to return only the content that matches all of the currently checked
  boxes, hiding all the rest.
- If no boxes are checked, everything
  should show.

As previously discussed in the above question, goals A and C were accomplished with:

```
$('div.tags').delegate('input:checkbox', 'change', function()
{
     var $lis = $('.results > li').hide();
     //For each one checked
     $('input:checked').each(function()
     {
          $lis.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
     });      
});
```

and goal B was accomplished with:

```
var selector = $('input:checked').map(function ()
{
    return $(this).attr('rel');
}).get().join('.');
$lis.filter(selector).doWhatever();
```

But I don't know how to integrate these two scripts together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/tkLK6/

```
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function()
{
    var $lis = $('.results > li'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');

    if ($checked.length)
    {
        var selector = $checked.map(function ()
        {
            return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
        }).get().join('');

        $lis.hide().filter(selector).show();     
    }
    else
    {
        $lis.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I've taken a shot at understanding the logic at http://jsfiddle.net/gd276/7/ so far it hasn't worked.

I've seen what I'm trying to do at http://www.dfs.co.uk/sofas/leather-sofas/ but your code is a lot simpler.

I don't think I'm accounting for taking a List, refining it through Checkbox A, and then taking the remaining list and refining through Checkbox B. 

Let me know if what I'm trying to do would be a massive script.