# display no results message with checkbox filtering

Tags: jquery, filter, tags

I found this solution that does exactly what i am looking for... provide check boxes and display the results that match ALL selected criteria.

[Re: jQuery Multiple Checkbox Page Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747669/re-jquery-multiple-checkbox-page-filter)

The only thing I would like to be able to add is a message if no results are returned based on the selected criteria, but I am pretty new to this. Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE

There's 1,001 ways of doing this... here's a simplistic solution. I can't suggest the "best" way of doing this because it depends on the rest of the site's architecture, your coding style, etc.

That said, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tkLK6/28/

```
if($results.length > 0) {
    $('.no-results-found').remove();
    $results.show();
} else {
    $('.results').append('<li class="no-results-found">No results found.</li>');
}
```

---

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tkLK6/27/

Instead of:

```
$lis.hide().filter(selector).show();
```

Try:

```
var $results = $lis.hide().filter(selector);
    
if($results.length > 0) {
    $results.show();
} else {
    alert('no results found.');
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of doing it this way, but that looks great. Thanks. Would it be possible to keep the check boxes visible and display this message where the results normally would be instead of the alert window?

Answer (score 0):

here

```
$checked = $('input:checked');

if ($checked.length) {  
  //do something
} else {
  alert('empty');
}
```

or

```
$('input:checked').empty()
```